# extract the characters before () using grep

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I need to extract the characters before the character '('. My file structure is:

> rose(good)ook
>
> daisy()no
>
> lilly(bad)fine
>
> sunflower()nice

I need output file as in the form of:

```
rose

daisy

lilly

sunflower
```

can anybody tell the command for this.....

awk, grep or sed are preferable...

Comment: awk -F"\(" '{print $1}' file   i tried this command and its working. I want to know the command in grep...

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/(.*//' file
```

Comment: Works with a comma too. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Using `cut`:

```
$ <file cut -d \( -f 1
rose

daisy

lilly

sunflower
```

Using `sed`:

```
$ <file sed -e 's/\(.*\)(.*$/\1/'
rose

daisy

lilly

sunflower
```

Comment: Note that the behaviour will differ if there's more than one `(` per line.

Answer (score 3):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F'(' '{print $1}' file
rose

daisy

lilly

sunflower
```

or GNU `grep`:

```
grep -oP '.*?(?=\()' file
```

Comment: Or `grep -o '^[^(]*'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use cut command:

```
cut -f1 -d "(" file_name
```

Comment: How is this different than the answer given by @rahmu above?

Comment: @ChrisDown it's badly formated without any explanation ?